# Java Stream API - Group by items of an object's inner list

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a way to achieve the following example code, leveraging Java Stream API rather than having to create a `HashMap` and populate it inside double `forEach`es? I was trying to play around with `groupingBy` and `flatMap` but couldn't find a way out.

Having a list of Movies, where each one has a list of genres (Strings)...

```
class Movie {
    List<String> genres;
}
```

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
```

...I want to group all the movies by genre

```
Map<String, List<Movie>> moviesByGenre = new HashMap();
movies.stream()
        .forEach(movie -> movie.getGenres()
                .stream()
                .forEach(genre -> moviesByGenre
                        .computeIfAbsent(genre, k -> new ArrayList<>())
                        .add(movie)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is tricky because you cannot define a key for each `Movie` since such an object can appear under multiple keys.

The **best** solution is as far as I know equal to yours:

```
Map<String, List<Movie>> groupedMovies = new HashMap<>();
movies.forEach(movie -> {
    movie.getGenres().forEach(genre ->
        groupedMovies.computeIfAbsent(genre, g -> new ArrayList<>()).add(movie)
    );
});
```

If you want to "convert" this snippet into [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream), you have to start with *what you have* - which is the individual genres. Extract them from each `Movie` using `flatMap` and `distinct` to avoid duplicates. Then use a `Collector.toMap` to get the desired output.

- **Key:** `Function.identity()` to map each unique `genre` as a key itself.
- **Value:** Use another `Stream` to filter out the movies containing a particular `genre` to assign them to the key.

```
Map<String, List<Movie>> groupedMovies = movies.stream()
    .map(Movie::getGenres)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            genre -> movies.stream()
                           .filter(movie -> movie.getGenres().contains(genre))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

The procedural approach in the first snippet is faster, easier to read and understand. I don't recommend using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) here.

---

A note.. there is no meaning of using `forEach` right after `stream`: The sequence of `list.stream().forEach(...)` can be `list.forEach(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First we might want to create a `Pair` or `Tuple` as follows:

```
    public static class Pair {
        Movie movie;
        String genre;

        public Pair(Movie movie, String genre) {
            this.movie = movie;
            this.genre = genre;
        }
       
       // Getters omitted

    }
```

This can be a `Record` as well in Java 17.

Next, we can do the following with `toMap`:

```
Map<String, List<Movie>> map = movies.stream()
                .flatMap(movie -> movie.getGenres().stream().map(genre -> new Pair(movie, genre)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getGenre, pair -> new ArrayList<>(List.of(pair.getMovie())),
                        (existing, current) -> {
                            existing.addAll(current);
                            return existing;
                        }));
```

Or we can use `groupBy`:

```
Map<String, List<Movie>> map = movies.stream()
                .flatMap(movie -> movie.getGenres().stream().map(genre -> new Pair(movie, genre)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getGenre,
                        HashMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(Pair::getMovie, Collectors.toList())));
```

Essentially we create a `Pair` for every movie with its every possible `genre`. After we have this pairs, we are grouping them in a way to get rid of the `Pair`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;


class Movie {
        String type;
        String name;
        Movie(String type, String name)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.name = name;
        }

    public Movie(String type) {
            this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Movie> posts = new ArrayList<>();
        posts.add( new Movie("HORROR", "movie1"));
        posts.add( new Movie("HORROR", "movie1"));
        posts.add( new Movie("HORROR", "movie1"));
        posts.add( new Movie("COMEDY", "movie1"));
        posts.add( new Movie("COMEDY", "movie2"));
        posts.add( new Movie("COMEDY", "movie3"));
        posts.add( new Movie("COMEDY", "movie2"));


        Map<String, List<Movie>>postsPerType = posts.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Movie::getType));

        postsPerType.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key = "
            + k + ", Value = " + v.size()));

        Map<String, List<Movie>>postsPerName = posts.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Movie::getName));
        postsPerName.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key = "
            + k + ", Value = " + v.size()));

    }
}
```

```
Key = HORROR, Value = 3
Key = COMEDY, Value = 4
Key = movie3, Value = 1
Key = movie2, Value = 2
Key = movie1, Value = 4
```